# Get user birthday Facebook Graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to collect some information when a user log in through Facebook.
I'm able to get all the information i need except the users birthday

```
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=first_name,last_name,birthday,email,gender');
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');            // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfname = $graphObject->getProperty('first_name'); // To Get Facebook first name
        $fblname = $graphObject->getProperty('last_name');  // To Get Facebook last name
        $fbbday = $graphObject->getProperty('birthday');    // To Get Facebook birthday
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');       // To Get Facebook email ID
      $fgender = $graphObject->getProperty('gender');       // To Get Facebook gender
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
      $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
      $_SESSION['FIRST_NAME'] = $fbfname;
      $_SESSION['LAST_NAME'] = $fblname;
      $_SESSION['BIRTHDAY'] = $fbbday;
      $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
      $_SESSION['GENDER'] =  $fgender;
      checkuser($fbid,$fbfname,$femail);
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don´t ask for the correct permission:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,user_birthday'));
```

Btw, make sure to test this with an App Admin. `user_birthday` needs to get reviewed before everyone can use it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. please don´t forget to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

> What am i doing wrong?

You’re not asking the user for the permission necessary to access their birthday.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_birthday